# DAX: extract part of context to external variable

Tags: filtering, powerbi, dax

Im using same part of filter context in DAX in PowerBI in many measures. Is there a way I can "extract" shared part of context to some external Measure, or to create some global variable, so it coult be used across all the measures but if I need to update it, I could do it in just one place?

One of measures is listed below:

```
 Kandydaci brutto t-0 = 
VAR 
    startCY = [Start]
VAR 
    koniecCY = IF(
        HASONEVALUE(OkresyPromocji[koniec]);
        VALUES(OkresyPromocji[koniec]);
        IF(
            NOW() < MAX('Callendar Table'[Data]);
            NOW();
            DATE([Rok rekrutacji];11;30)
        )
    )
VAR
    wynik = 
    CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS(
            GROUPBY(
                'Baza';
                'Baza'[Poziom];
                'Baza'[ID_DANE_OSOBOWE];
                "Kandydaci"; COUNTX(CURRENTGROUP(); 'Baza'[ID_DANE_OSOBOWE])
            )
        );
        ALLEXCEPT(
            'Baza';
            Poziom[Poziom]; 
            Absolwent[Absolwent]; 
            'Specjalności'[Specjalności]; 
            kody_pocztowe[POWIAT_BI];
            'Baza'[Wiek podczas zapisu]; 
            'Baza'[Zwrotkowicz]; 
            'Baza'[Maturzysta];
            'Baza'[OBYWATELSTWO];
            'Baza'[Płeć]);
        'Baza'[ZLOZENIE_PODANIA_DATA] >= startCY;
        'Baza'[ZLOZENIE_PODANIA_DATA] <= koniecCY
    )
RETURN
IF(
    NOW() <= MAX('Callendar Table'[Data]);
    IF(ISBLANK(wynik); 0 ; wynik);
    BLANK()
)
```

The

> ALLEXCEPT(
>               'Baza';
>               Poziom[Poziom]; 
>               Absolwent[Absolwent]; 
>               'Specjalności'[Specjalności]; 
>               kody_pocztowe[POWIAT_BI];
>               'Baza'[Wiek podczas zapisu]; 
>               'Baza'[Zwrotkowicz]; 
>               'Baza'[Maturzysta];
>               'Baza'[OBYWATELSTWO];
>               'Baza'[Płeć])

part is the one I would like to be able to load into measures from some external measure or global variable, rest of filter context differs.

Comment: There  is no good solution currently; a workaround is decribed here: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/creating-table-functions-in-dax-using-detailrows/

Comment: @Uzzy try to put `wynik` inside the formula and the other variables as well, i.e., without variables.